# Selenium is not accessing the print dialog box to click on "OK" button, How I can switch to print dialog and click on OK button,

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following code is not working, Please hep me to save the PDF. I need to save the pdf in a location.

Please help me on this.
    public class amazonpacking extends Dictionary {

```
static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public static void before() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",
            "C:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(AmazonURL);
}

@Test(priority = 0)
public void Amazon() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("mandkanw@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("*****");

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();

    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.delay(5000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

}

}
```

Comment: You should consider removing your username and password or someone may use it nefariously :)

Comment: It is still visible in edit history. You'd better reopen this ticket. Also try to add more details as questions like "What's wrong with my code" should be closed